# How to send the jwt token to the frontend through headers on nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, cookies, jwt

Okay so i have simple application. When the user logs in, i create a token with jwt. I have been using res.cookie() to send the token to the frontend but due to reasons, i can no longer use cookies, How do i use headers to achieve the same goal?

Basically, this is what i want to achieve:

//Login function

```
const login = async (req, res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body
    
    const user = await User.findOne({email})
    if(!user){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid credentials')
    }

    const isPasswordCorrect = await user.comparePassword(password)
    if(!isPasswordCorrect){
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('Invalid credentials')
    }

    const token = user.createJWT()
    res.cookie("token", token).json(user)     //send token here to the frontend through headers instead of cookies
}
```

//Auth middleware to verify the token:

```
const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    const {token} = req.cookies    //get the token here from the headers instead of cookies

    if(token){
        try{

            const {userId, name} = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET)
            req.user = {userId, name}  
            next()
        }
        catch(error){
            throw new UnauthenticatedError('Authentication invalid')
        }
    }else{
        throw new UnauthenticatedError('no token')
    }
}
```

//Login component on the frontend

```
const handleLogin = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        try {
            const {data} = await axios.post('/auth/login', {email,password})
            successfulNotification('login successful')
            setUser(data)
            setRedirect(true)
        } catch (error) {
            errorNotification('login unsuccessful, please try again later')
            return error
        }        
    }
```

Comment: Is this a nextjs project?

Comment: no its a mern project

Answer (score 0):

From the [NodeJS HTTP Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#requestsetheadername-value), you can use this to set an header:

```
res.setHeader("name", "value");
```

From the [Express Documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.set) instead:

```
res.set("name", "value");
```

You can also pass an object for multiple headers at once:

```
res.set({
    "name1": "value1",
    "name2": "value2"
});
```

So, you would just have to replace `res.cookie("token", token).json(user)` with `res.setHeader("token", token)`.

You can get the header contents with `req.headers["name"]`:

```
jwt.verify(req.headers["token"]);
```